# Troubleshooting CSS Layout

Tags: html, css

I have built a template to layout what I intend to accomplish. Everything seems to work well with what I have learned from the stackoverflow community.

However, the Footer which is its own container and has "section7" as another DIV is not displaying as 150 pixels in height. Basically all sections have fixed height except for Section 5 and Section 6 which have to scale in height depending on the browser window size or content that will be placed inside the section. So if content is sparse, I just want the height to be 100% of the remaining browser space so that the website is top to bottom. However if there is content that is lengthy obviously I want the middle section to adapt and continue as required. Hope I am making sense.

The challenge is I don't know where I am wrong and thus do not know how to pose the question in the search function as I imagine it is an easy task for those with experience. Any help is appreciated.

**The HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="section1">section 1</div>
        <div class="section2">section 2</div>
        <div class="section3">section 3</div>
        <div class="section4">section 4</div>  

    </div>

    <div class="middle">

        <div class="section5">section 5</div>
        <div class="section6">section 6</div> 

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

        <div class="section7">section 7</div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:#DBDBDB
}

div.container   {
    width: 1200px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;      
}

div.header  {
    height: 100px;      
}

div.middle  {
    min-height: 400;        
}

div.footer  {
    height: 150px;
}

div.section1 {
    background-color:#FF0004;
    height: 100px;
    width: 275px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

div.section2 {
    background-color:#FFA600;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

div.section3 {
    background-color:#00C304;
    height: 50px;
}

div.section4 {
    background-color:#DFDD00;
    height: 50px;
}

div.section5 {
    background-color:#0A00FF;
    width: 275px;
    height: 400px;
    float:left;
    height: 100vh;
}

div.section6 {
    background-color:#CB05B1;
    width: 925px;
    height: 400px;
    float:right;
    height: 100vh;
}

div.section7 {
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Explaining the question and not giving your life background might get you a better response.  I didn't see anything even hinting towards a question/issue in the first paragraph

Comment: I made a fiddle of it for you @andy-parker here: https://jsfiddle.net/2L55g0f9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating elements need to be cleared so that elements following align correctly and do not move into the elements you have floated. Section 5 and Section 6.

Add the following class definition to your stylesheet

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

Change the following tag     `<div class="middle">` to `<div class="middle clearfix">`

HTML5 also includes `<header>` and `<footer>` elements, as well as `<article>` tags to make the document language more semantic. So for HTML5 you can use

```
<header>

    <div class="section1">section 1</div>
    <div class="section2">section 2</div>
    <div class="section3">section 3</div>
    <div class="section4">section 4</div>  

</header>
```

And

```
<footer>

    <div class="section7">section 7</div>

</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/raythcael/s49o4rjz/2/

Answer (score 0):

To make `.section7` have a height of 150px add `display: inline-block;`

```
div.section7 {
    background-color: #9E9E9E;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/zvkxj6v8/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the height isn't working as it should is because the Div's above it is set to "float". Add "clear: both;" to div.section7 to clear the floats.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/2L55g0f9/1/

because section 5 and 6 are floated, you're not seeing the height of section 7. All i did was clearfix it, and you got your height :)

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
```